# Kubemq-go missing tags in response to query via GRPC

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, message-queue, grpc-go

I am developing a microservices interacting via kubemq in cluster. When sending query response (via GRPC protocol) with some tags attached:

```golang
    err := client.NewResponse().
                    SetRequestId(query.Id).
                    SetResponseTo(query.ResponseTo).
                    SetExecutedAt(time.Now()).
                    SetMetadata("this is a response").
                    SetBody([]byte("got your query, you are good to go")).
                    SetTags(map[string]string{"key0":"val0","key1":"val1"}).
                    Send(ctx)
```

I descovered I do not see them at the receiver response:

```golang
    response, err := client.NewQuery().
        SetId("some-query-id").
        SetChannel(channel).
        SetMetadata("some-metadata").
        SetBody([]byte("hello kubemq - sending a query, please reply")).
        SetTimeout(1 *time.Second).
        Send(ctx)
    fmt.Println("Response Tags Received:",response.Tags)
```

Output shows:

```
Response Tags Received: map[]
```

So response.Tags is empty. Then I took a look at the official query example https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-go/blob/master/examples/rpc/query/main.go. Note it is using rest protocol

```golang
    client, err := kubemq.NewClient(ctx,
        kubemq.WithUri("http://localhost:9090"),
        kubemq.WithClientId("test-query-client-id"),
        kubemq.WithTransportType(kubemq.TransportTypeRest))
```

After I did add some tags to the query response (as shown in the first code in this post) it was showing tags in the response properly, but when I did switch protocol to grpc:

```golang
        kubemq.WithAddress("localhost", 50000),
    //  kubemq.WithUri("http://localhost:9090"),
        kubemq.WithClientId("test-query-client-id"),
        kubemq.WithTransportType(kubemq.TransportTypeGRPC))
    //  kubemq.WithTransportType(kubemq.TransportTypeRest))
```

It start to stop showing tags in the response.

I did some updated kubemqgo examples here https://github.com/Aidamir/kubemq-go/tree/master/examples/rpc
Illustrating this issue. There is 2 directories query-tags-rest, query-tags-grpc and also query is the official query example which I was using as a source. There is only a few modifications for the client protocol. Please explain me, why tags are not sending when using grpc? May be there is some protocol restrictions which I was missing from documentation?

Comment: Since kubemq is not opensource software it is hard to diagnose whether this is a bug or not used as intended. There is no architecture description on their website and no hints how to debug kubemq. Perhaps a different product would be a better choice.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for point me that kubemq server side is not open source I was missing that. What do you think which can be alternative? (we just refused from rabbitmq)

Comment: That is a very broad question, the answer highly depending on your use case and environment. I am sorry, but I can not answer that in the scope of a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Thomas I thought this is the source code for kubemq server https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-go. Is it not ?

Comment: That is the client library, not the server.

Comment: @Viraj. I am using kubemq for cluster bus.(Event pub/sub, RPC ) Good impression. Still have not seen it in production, but under stress tests all works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, I posted an issue https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-go/issues/7 and it was fixed fastly. You must update to version 1.3.3 to avoid this problem.